# Deprecate term in SharePoint Online Term Store not working

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, powershell-7.3, pnp.powershell

I'm trying to deprecate some terms based on the guid using PnP PowerShell. The command executes without error but I don't see the term deprecated in the term store. I'm using
[Set-PnPTerm](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPTerm.html#-deprecated).

```
$t_group = "People"
$t_set = "Department"
$t_Id = "5c92696e-f646-4a3a-95a7-826ed4947563"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -Interactive

Set-PnPTerm -Identity $t_Id -TermSet $t_set -TermGroup $t_group -Deprecated $true
```

Comment: Have a try to replace GUID with corresponding name, would this help?